# How to find an element with XPath in an arbitrary position in a set of nesting divs

Tags: html, xml, xpath

What XPath expression will allow me to find an element in arbitrary position in a set of nesting `<div>`s and *only* those elements?

For example, how to find all the `<a>` elements except the last one in this HTML fragment:

```
<div id="0">
   <a href="first.com"/>
   <div id="1"></div>
   <div id="2">
      <div id="2.1">
          <div id="2.11">
             <a href="second.com" />
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="3"><a href="third.com" /></div>
</div>
<a href="dont_find_this_one.com" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//a
```

will select all `a` elements in the document.

---

Update per requirements clarification comment:

This XPath,

```
//div[@id="0"]//a
```

will select all `a` elements under all `id="0"` `div` elements in the document.

Comment: Sorry, not clear.  all "a" elements in a set of nesting divs and only those "a" elements.  Edited OP.

Comment: Updated answer to show how to limit `a` selection to descendants of `id="0" div` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of writing it could be :

```
 //a[ancestor::div[@id="0"]]
```

Select all anchor elements with a specific common ancestor (`div` with a specific attribute).

Other options, but more risky :

```
//a[parent::div]
```

Select all anchor elements with a `div` element as a parent.

```
(//a)[not(position()=last())]
```

Select all anchor elements except the last one present on the page.